# Form validation on primeng p-autoComplete component not working

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a form with several elements. Within that form I have two `primeng p-autoComplete` components. For some reason my reactive form validation does not get detected on these components, but does on all other components of the form.

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="ui-g">
  <div class="ui-g-6">
    <label>Generator Name</label>
    <div class="ui-inputgroup">
      <p-autoComplete name="name" formControlName="gen" [suggestions]="hint"
                      (completeMethod)="filter($event)"  field="name"
                      [forceSelection]="true" [dropdown]="true" placeholder="Select"></p-autoComplete>
      <div *ngIf="formErrors['gen']">
        {{formErrors['generator']}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

ts:

```
hint: Gen[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
    this.initVariable();
  }

initVariable() {
    this.formErrors = {
      'gen': '',
    };

    this.validationMessages = {
      'gen': {
        'required': 'Gen is required'
      }
    };

  }

createForm() {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      gen: [null, Validators.required]
    });

    this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.onValueChanged());
    this.onValueChanged();
  }

onValueChanged() {
    if (this.formGroup === null || this.formGroup === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    validateForm(this.formGroup, this.formErrors, this.validationMessages);
  }

validateForm(form: FormGroup, formErrors, validationMessages) {
  for (const field in formErrors) {
    if (formErrors.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
      formErrors[field] = '';
      const control = form.get(field);

      if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
        const error = lookupError(control, validationMessages[field]);
        setErrorIfExists(formErrors, field, error);
      }
    }
  }
}

function lookupError (control, messages) {
  for (const key in control.errors) {
    if (control.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return messages[key];
    }
  }
}
```

I only included the form code for the `p-autoComplete` component in which the validation does not work. For all other components the validation works with using the `formErrors` and `validationMessages` arrays. One other thing I did try was having my ts implement `DoCheck` and then have the `ngDoCheck` method which just calls `validateForm()` function because according to primeng "AutoComplete either uses setter based checking or ngDoCheck to realize if the suggestions has changed to update the UI". This does get called whenever I change the value of the `p-autoComplete` component but still doesn't do the validation.

Comment: Did you found a solution for the validation?